# archiving / copying all the values in column A to column C based on date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-apps-script-editor

archiving / copying all the values in column A to column C based on date. Also, if the date is change, a new set of values will be copied and the previous value won't be deleted.I was working on a daily schedule of every employee at the same time it will be recorded as their attendance based on the date. Can someone help me?

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOBsi.png)

[**Example 2** : if I change the date, the previous record won't get deleted and will copy a new set of values based on date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X1u0.png)

If I press the (save button) I want all the the values from column B2:B4 will be copied to column F2:F4 based on the date on column C1

The 2nd screenshot shows if I change the date and press again the (save button) the previous value won't get deleted and a new set of values will be copied based on the actual date on column C1

Comment: Please don't shout at us.

Comment: Would you please summarise your research for this question; we wouldn't want to double up on that.

Comment: Hello @Pamela Ann Nicole! Would you mind sharing more information - like a sample sheet of your data and what exactly you are trying to achieve. Also, if you have any code snippets available, those would be of great help as well! Cheers!

Comment: I've already edited my post and paste a sample sheet on it. I just want to record all the scheduled of the employee based on date. But, if I change the date, the previous record won't be deleted. I've tried using Match and Index it works for one column only, If I change the date on Column C the previous record gets deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve your issue I suggest you to use Apps Script and write a script and use this function:

```
function dateFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currDate = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var originRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B4");
  var headers = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0];
  var dateFound = false;

  for (var i=5; i<headers.length && !dateFound; i++) {
    if (currDate.toString() == headers[i].toString()) {
      originRange.copyTo(sheet.getRange(2, i + 1, 3));
      dateFound = true;
    }
  }

  if (!dateFound)
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Date not found!");  
}
```

The script works by gathering all the dates from your headers and will try to see if there's a match with the date from the `C1` cell. If a match has been found, the values will be copied correspondingly, otherwise, an alert prompt will show up specifying that the date has not been found.

Now, you will need to link this function to a **button** so it will only be executed when you click it.

You can easily do that by inserting a **drawing** and shape/draw it so it will resemble a button of your liking. You will have to **Save and Close** it.

[image]

Then, when you right click on it the option of **Assign a script** will appear and you have to put the name of the function from above in there, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

So now, every time you press the **Save** button, the script will be executed.

Furthermore, I suggest you read the following links since they might help you:

1. [Apps Script Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet);
2. [Sheet Class .getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange());
3. [Range Class .copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination).

Comment: @PamelaAnnNicole, I'm happy to hear this, you're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving your problem :) See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Cheers!

Comment: I also have another question, how can I tag you there? Thanks

Comment: If you want to tag other users just use the `@` in front of the username :)

Comment: Is there a way for you to see the new post I've created?